# Setting margin to the jtable printed to pdf

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I am using the following code for printing *JTable to PDF*.Unfortunately the printed page doesn't have a left margin and also the table headers are not printed.

I'm using `iText` for this and don't wanna use any other API for this. ***How can i solve this problem?***

```
private void print() {
    Document document = new Document();
    try {
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("jTable.pdf"));

      document.open();
      PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

      cb.saveState();
      Graphics2D g2 = cb.createGraphicsShapes(800, 500);

      Shape oldClip = g2.getClip();
      g2.clipRect(0, 0, 800, 500);

      jTable.print(g2);
      g2.setClip(oldClip);

      g2.dispose();
      cb.restoreState();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    document.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use g2.translate() before calling print() to shift table content